# What is the best way to "measure" a uniform distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

Is there a way to tell the quality of a distribution which is close to uniformity?

e.g. I have the following discrete distribution of values:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]

which is pretty close to a perfect uniform distribution.

Subtracting the mean of the distribution above from the mean of the perfect distribution is the closest solution I found, however I was hoping to have a more elevated solution to this problem.

I am not a mathematican/statistics so please forgive me any mistakes

Comment: Take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance and in particular the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: Actually comparing to a discrete distribution means you can't exactly use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, because its theory is based on the assumption that the target distribution you're comparing to is continuous. One possible workaround: assuming that there's no possible chance that you had any values outside 0,1,...,9 and just happened to not see them in the sample, one possible approach is to treat this as categorical data and use the usual chi square test; see https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/goodness-fit-tests-discrete-distributions/

Comment: (My assumption would make sense if, for example, you got your results by rolling a 10-sided die and are curious whether the die is fair.)